# Extract house numbers from address string

Tags: php, regex, street-address

I am importing user data from a foreign database on demand. While i keep house numbers separate from the street names, the other database does not.

I use

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!')
```

To rule out the numbers. This works fine for an addressline like this:

```
streetname 60
```

But it does not work for an addressline like this:

```
streetname 60/2/3
```

In that case i end up extracting 60, and /2/3 stay in the name of the street.

Unfortunately i am not a regex expert. Quite to the contrary. My problem is that i need to be able to not only detect numerics, but also slashes and hyphens.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`preg_match_all('![0-9/-]+!', 'streetname 60/2/3', $matches);`

Comment: @CummanderCheckov Do you "understand" how the expression works ?

Comment: Yes, it is rather simple in this case. Although i have no idea what the callsigns are for.

Answer (score 0):

to give a definite answer we would have to know the patterns in your data.

for example, in Germany we sometimes have house numbers like `13a` or `23-42`, which could also be written as `23 - 42`

one possible solution would be to match *everything* after a whitespace that starts with a digit

```
preg_match_all('!\s(\d.*)!', 'streetname 60/2/3', $matches);
```

this would produce false positives, though, if you have American data with streets like `13street`

Comment: That is really good input. As i am dealing with mainly German, Austrian and Swiss street names. However, a problem with using the whitespace as indicator is that it could occur within a street name as well. Perhaps there is a way to use the LAST whitespace BEFORE the first digit, as an indicator?

Comment: this will match exactly that: a whitespace, a digit, and everything following the digit until the end. everything starting with the digit will be considered as part of the group and put in `$matches[1]` (if no flags are set)

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not use Regex. Will only return when it sees the first number, exploded by space. Ideal for addresses like e.g. 12 Street Road, Street Name 1234B

```
function getStreetNumberFromStreetAddress($streetAddress){
  $array = explode(' ',$streetAddress);

  if (count($array) > 0){
    foreach($array as $a){
      if (is_numeric($a[0])){
        return $a;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```